# Where can I find tall grass?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Now that grass cannot be hoed for seeds and instead we must use tall grass:

> Added tall grass in some biomes,
>
> Seeds are now found in tall grass, using a hoe on the ground no longer
>   works

What are these 'some biomes'? And will said grass grow in existing biomes?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've been going through a newly-generated world, traveling across several biomes, and I've seen tall grass everywhere there's regular grass: forests, savannah, plains, etc.

The only biomes in which it doesn't seem to spawn are tundra, deserts, and (of course) the Nether.

Tall grass is incredibly common: If you haven't seen a ton of it already, one thing to keep in mind is that new terrain features generally don't spawn on already-generated chunks, and you'll have to travel to a new, unexplored area to see them.

To confirm this, I loaded an existing world I had which spanned a few different biomes (tundra, taiga, forest, grassland). There was no tall grass in any of the pre-generated chunks. However, I found several instances of tall grass immediately after walking into an area that caused the game to generate a new chunk.

**Edit (thanks, Kurley):** as of 1.6.6, you can [spawn tall grass](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bonemeal#Fertilizer) yourself:

> When applied to a grass block, one bone meal is consumed and tall grass, and occasionally flowers, forms around and on the grass block.

Comment: Great, thank you! When the modders have finished their hard work, I am hoping some tallgrass command appears to generate it.

Comment: @The Communist Duck - Although I'm sure that you are aware now, for the benefit of others; Using bone meal on the ground will cause tall grass and flowers to spawn since patch 1.6.6.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to travel, you can use bone meal on grass to make either tall grass or flowers.

Answer (score 0):

Just run to your nearest village. I found 5 rows of wheat ready for picking. Had seeds to start my own farm, and had more than enough wheat to start making bread. Easy peasy